# IF Statment Logic Meaning

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on a project but I was stumped to see this piece of code
**if ((array.length - 1 - i) % 2 === 1)** I am just curious as to how it works?

```js
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];

const validateCred = (array) => {
  let total = 0;
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // console.log(array[i]) 
    if ((array.length - 1 - i) % 2 === 1) { /*I would like to know what does this do when put in a if statment array.length - 1 - i  */
      array[i] *= 2;
      // console.log(array[i]) 
      if (array[i] > 9) {
        array[i] -= 9;
      }
    }
    total += array[i]
    console.log(total)
  }
  return total % 10 === 0;

};
console.log(validateCred(valid1))
```

Comment: Testing `something % 2` is used to tell if a number is even or odd.

Comment: Got it thank you, do you know by any chance what this condition means? 
if ((array.length - 1 - i) that comes before it?

Comment: It's subtracting `i` from the last index of the array. So on the first iteration, that's `0`, the next iteration is `1`, and so on.

Comment: This is basically just alternating between muliplying by 2 and subtracting 9 from the array elements.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, just found it odd that the for loop also starts from the last index then goes backward.

Comment: I guess the specification says that the last element should be subtracted, the next to last should be multiplied, and so on. If it started from `0`, the condition would still have to depend on the length.

Answer (score 0):

- `array.length - 1`: the last index of the array
- `lastIndex - i`: work through the array from back to front (typically)
- `someIndex % 2 === 1`: is the index modulus 2 equal to 1 (meaning, is it odd?)

But then the loop iterates from the last index to the first index, so the `- i` just makes it iterate from front to back again. Which seems needlessly complex.

This code is pretty funky...

Comment: Got it, I found it weird as I thought the for loop was already set to start at the last index of the array and count backward, sorry I am very new to JS.